# Is it possible to send info from react form to zoho crm?

Tags: reactjs, zoho

I have React app and generated zoho form but this form isn't configurable, for example, I cannot validate it with react, after submit all pages reloads and redirected to the zoho thank you page(no ajax calls). Also, I cannot add some custom logic to it. I didn't find examples in the internet of sending info to zoho through some api. Is it possible in react apps?

I checked this api docs page but didn't find any examples https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/v2/#api-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, the answer is no. You can not validate Zoho Generate Form with react as the form is originally hosted on Zoho Server and you can just embed it in your application using iframe. Even the javascript embedding option is creating an iframe.

The link you referenced is for Zoho CRM API and is not related to Zoho Forms.